# How can a I make inline-block stay in a single line but still fit the available width?

Tags: html, css

I have the following demo code the demonstrates my problem. I want to add some decoration beside the title via CSS and have this problem. If the title is short enough it works as expected, but if the title is longer, when the text wraps around but not enough to be inside the div.base.

How can I make the second sample it looks like the third (fake) sample below?
[image]

Just to be clear, I want the div contents to appear "inline" with only the middle div being allowed to word-wrap, the div contents should stay within the container width without adding extra spaces between the divs.

```
<html>
    <style>
        .base { font-size:32pt; text-align:center; border:solid; display: block; white-space:nowrap; width:400px;}
        .base span, .base::before, .base::after { display: inline-block; border:solid; white-space:normal;}
        .base::before { content: "\00a0-\00a0"; }
        .base::after { content: "\00a0-\00a0"; }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="base">
            <span>Short text</span>
        </div>
        <div class="base">
            <span>Testing some longer text</span>
        </div>
        <div class="base">
            <span>Fake some <br>longer text</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to go, the second one better (flex), but dependent on browser support:

1.) You can use a `max-width` with a percentage or (better) `calc` value on that span:

```css
.base {
  font-size: 32pt;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 400px;
}

.base span,
.base::before,
.base::after {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid;
  white-space: normal;
}

.base::before {
  content: "\00a0-\00a0";
}

.base::after {
  content: "\00a0-\00a0";
}
.x2 span {
  max-width: calc(100% - 112px);
}
```

```html
<div class="base x1">
  <span>Short text</span>
</div>
<div class="base x2">
  <span>Testing some longer text</span>
</div>
<div class="base x3">
  <span>Fake some <br>longer text</span>
</div>
```

2.) Here's the second solution using flexbox:

```css
.base {
  font-size: 32pt;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

base span {
}

.base span,
.base::before,
.base::after {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid;
  white-space: normal;
}

.base::before {
  content: "\00a0-\00a0";
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.base::after {
  content: "\00a0-\00a0";
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="base x1">
  <span>Short text</span>
</div>
<div class="base x2">
  <span>Testing some longer text</span>
</div>
<div class="base x3">
  <span>Fake some <br>longer text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ryan why - what's the problem? It does exactly what he wants - he just has to adjust the percentage to his needs

Comment: For one thing, it wouldn't scale correctly if the containing div becomes wider/thinner. While this might not be an issue if the container div will be of a fixed width, at that point you might as well just set the max-width in exact px/em. A better solution would be to use calc, for example: "max-width: calc(100% - 120px)".

Comment: sure, using `calc` is even better, but also that contains a percentage... thanks for pointing that out - I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Actually, it's not an issue at all. The problem with `max-width: 70%` is that the space remaining to the left and right of the span would also scale with the width of the div, even though the content (the ::before and ::after) remain at a fixed size. `max-width: calc(100% - 120px)` keeps the remaining space on each side the same.

Comment: Ryan is correct, this is a sample to illustrate my problem, in reality the width is not know beforehand neither how large will the side decorations be.

Comment: I have tried the flex approach before, maybe I'm missing something, but when using flex with text word-wraping inside, the middle div spans all available space, adding extra space between it and the side decorations. If I can use the flex but make the middle div only have  the needed width, than it is a great solution, otherwise a `display:table` and `display: table-cell` can have a better appearance.